# Ich habe bitcoin-qt auf neuen Computer installiert und komplette blockchain runtergeladen. Wie verbinde oder oeffne ich meine alte Wallet?

Tags: wallet.dat

Ich habe bitcoin-qt auf neuen Computer installiert und komplette blockchain runtergeladen. Wie verbinde oder oeffne ich meine alte Wallet die auf alten Computer erstellt wurde?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close bitcoin-qt

Copy your old wallet.dat file into the directory that contains the wallet.
If you installed with standard path, it will be:
c:\users\yourpcusername\AppData\Roaming\Bitcoin\wallets

just rename or delete the old wallet.dat file.

Restart bitcoin-qt. It will now rescan, this will take a few hours.

Comment: Hello, your answer was very good and the result was successfully. The rescan took 5.5h! Incredible! Thank you very much.